# Sending SMS/Text Messages through GMail

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

I have done a bit of research online regarding this. I found out that Google Chat used to have this function for sending SMS/text messages. Google Hangouts can do that, however I will need to sign up for Project Fi account. Is there any existing methods that can do this (without a cost)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you to those who down voted this. Please do know that I am asking for some advice (which I might have not found or missed out). It's not that I didn't do my own research before hand.

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 0):

Some phone carriers have a way to send sms from email.

For example, 3057689900@att.com would send an sms to that phone number.

The only catch is that you would have to know what phone company your recipient is affiliated to.

Comment: Thank you. It is notable that I am outside US. Will this method still work? I googled and found that <10-digit-number>@<sms-gateway> may work, but I think it only applies for within US?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can send to a us number from any gmail in the world. I am not sure if phone providers in your country have this method. In my country, Colombia, I have not tried this yet..

Comment: I'm sending from Singapore, possibly to Thailand, Vietnam, China, Japan. Do you think this method will still work? (given I know the recipient's affiliated phone company)?

Comment: I would prefer to look for an sms gateway api (google it).  These charge you per message sent. Send the messages out via API calls (with a server), much more "standard" and certain to work.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am looking for a solution without cost. So I'm thinking if there is a way to do it or setup my own SMS gateway with API calls.

Comment: Google it.. "How to set up my own sms gateway". Probably not so expensive..

Comment: Definitely hire a programmer, someone with experience in server programming can help.